# Grant user to alter view and SP's but deny to create/drop user tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I would like to limit a user to create / drop user tables but this user needs to alter/view Stored procedures and views. Is there any way to manage both at the same time ?

When i make this user a member of ddladmin role, it can create / drop tables which i dont want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below script yo give view and alter permission to a user.

```
GRANT ALTER,VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[YourSchema] TO [YourUser]
```

Comment: doesnt this allow them to drop tables as well?